# Saving a Textbox into file with GetWindowText : std::string to LPWSTR

Tags: c++, winapi, stdstring

I tried various variations of code on how to save the content of a textbox to file, like:

```
std::string str;   // same problem with std::wstring
GetWindowTextW(hwndEdit, str.c_str(), 0);   // same problem with GetWindowText
std::ofstream file;
file.open("myfile.txt");
file << str;
file.close();
```

but they all present some kind of string variable conversion error:

```
main.cpp(54) : error C2664: 'GetWindowTextW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char *' to 'LPWSTR'
```

**How to work with `GetWindowText` or `GetWindowTextW`?**

*Note: I don't know the length in advance: it can be 128 as well as 1167 chars or more.*

Comment: Your saving wide text into (a) a narrow string that is (b) read-only, and (c) has zero length regardless, *all* of which are wrong.  And you *can* know the length in advance, see; [**`GetWindowTextLengthA`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633521(v=vs.85).aspx) and [**`GetWindowTextA`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx) for narrow functions that may do what you seek.

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig , I tried `std::string str (GetWindowTextLengthA(hwndEdit));` to create a string that can contain the right length, but still some errors. Would you have an idea for an answer? I'm browsing many/ string tutorials docs but cannot make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're invoking *undefined behavior* (UB) in your code. I think this is what you're trying to do, but only you know for sure.

```
int len = GetWindowTextLengthA(hwndEdit);
if (len > 0)
{
    std::vector<char> text(len+1);
    GetWindowTextA(hwndEdit, &text[0], len+1);

    std::ofstream file("myfile.txt", std::ios::out  | std::ios::binary);
    file.write(&text[0], len);
}
```

I haven't a Windows box handy, but I think this is either correct or darn close to it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I get `error C2039: 'vector' : is not a member of 'std'`. By the way, what is "UB" ?

Comment: @Basj `#include <vector>` in your include list, and UB means *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Ok for `include`. It nearly works, but the output file contains weird content : `426f 6e6a 6f75 7220 7173 646b 6a71 640d
0d0a 7173 6473 716b 6a64 716b 6864 7371
00`... What do you mean by `you're invoking undefined behaviour` ?

Comment: @Basj Heh, was afraid of that. Are you dumping Unicode text in your edit box ? If so, you can translate to UTF-8 before the write, but the code is considerably more complicated. There are multiple answers on SO in dealing with Unicode to UTF-8 translation. (or just write the file as unicode, if that is an option).

Comment: I don't know, I'm just writing text with keyboard. Here is the full code : https://github.com/josephernest/NeverForget/blob/master/src/neverforget.cpp ... I'm totally lost about where/why/when to add Unicode handling or not in this code :(

Comment: Something doesn't seem right. If you step in the code in your debugger, are the chars in your edit box in the vector? if you're using Visual studio it will be obvious. Set a break point on the line after `GetWindowTextA` and examine that vector.

Comment: No I don't use VisualStudio. I do all in SublimeText and no EDI

Comment: ugh. something definitely isn't right. I translated the first few octets in that output and it looks something like `onjour qsdk` Dunno if that is what you typed. Your editor may be picking up the terminating null char (my bad for writing one too many bytes) and showing the result in hex-binary. unfortunately I have to hit the sack, as I have to wake up in two hours. i'll check back later. In the mean time, try writing `len-1` bytes to the output file. Be back in awhile.

Comment: This should be `std::vector<wchar_t>`, since the error message in the question states that `GetWindowTextW` was called. Note the trailing `W` to indicate the wide version, i.e. UTF-16. You should also use `std::wofstream` to match the encoding.

Comment: @WhozCraig the UTF8 problem is solved by changing `len` to `len+1`. Hurrah!

Comment: @Basj So glad you got it working. I didn't have time to revisit. but approved your edit. Thanks for the update! Best of luck.